# Background Image CSS inline not working

Tags: html, css

I looked through a few other posts and couldn't find a solution.

```html
<div id="particles-js" style="height:540px; background-color:#232741; background-image: url(" https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Donald_Trump_official_portrait.jpg "); "></div>
```

I have this code, while background-color here seems to work I cannot seem to set the background to this image of Donald Trump. I have tried my hardest with the different permutations like backgroundImage and nothing seems to work.

Perhaps one of you can spot the issue here?

By the way the styling does need to be inline for my current purposes.

Comment: You're quotes are incorrect. You can't use `"` when you use that to start/end style=. So change `url("..."` to `url('...'`

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you my friend

Comment: And my use of you're was incorrect. "Your"

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the quote inside `background-image: url()`

Try this code.

```html
<div id="particles-js" style="height:540px; background-color:#232741; background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Donald_Trump_official_portrait.jpg);"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using double quotes on an attribute value style=" "  " ", so this is not correct use single quotes like this style="  ' ' "